# Textarea content overflowing outside the container in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css

[image: Text Overflowing in Mozilla]

So I was testing the HTML/CSS code on Chrome and Firefox. The textarea seems to be rendering fine on Chrome, but when I shifted to Mozilla for testing it, the text is overflowing to the top.

```
profile-post-commentbox{
width: 90%;
border: none;
background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.5);
padding-left: 10px;
resize: vertical;
overflow: auto;
min-height: 40px;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="profile-post-commentsection">
    <textarea class="profile-post-commentbox"></textarea>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I even tried setting up higher padding. It doesn't work, the text overflows to the top of the container.

Comment: Could you include the HTML also?  Your styles don't have a # (id) or . (class) preface.  This means your styles aren't loading, unless you created a custom tag (profile-post-commentbox) or there is a typo here.

Comment: updated with HTML code, the styles are loading... Sorry I didn't include the HTML before that led you to think that.. @JenniferGoncalves

Comment: can you also include the HTML of the container above that seems to be overlaying your textarea?

Comment: Is there any way you could include a link to your website or is this a local development environment?